# is it safe to delete SetupCache from .Net 4 installation

Tags: windows-xp, .net-framework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Very large unknown (to me) files in .NET 4.0 directory](https://superuser.com/questions/193586/very-large-unknown-to-me-files-in-net-4-0-directory)

I got this directory:

`c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SetupCache\` which is 228 MB in size... yes.. and it seems it is just unpacked content from installation file.

Any of you tried to delete it ? How it will behave in a long run, will all apps that need .Net work ok ?